# "SSH auth method: private key" vagrant problem

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

i want to setup a webserver using vagrant and i have problem with the command "vagrant up":

First i work on a virtual machine (Virtualbox) and i have to build my vagrant project inside virtualbox so I created a Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.68.8"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.gui = true
    end
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => ".provision/bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Then when i execute the command "vagrant up" it hangs on the last line:

```
zakaria@server:~/webserver$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
```

and the gui stucks too :
This is the picture knowing that i am already enabled VT-X in virtualbox settings. 
[image]

Comment: `vagrant up --debug` and you will see where it hangs to loop into the error

Answer (score 0):

One thing I encourage you to look is if you have HyperV on, Vagrant docs specifically say to disable it: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation#windows-virtualbox-and-hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a similar problem and mine was related (mostly) to `Docker Desktop Client for Windows`.

I took the nuclear option and removed `Docker` and disabled a ton of features relating to *containers* and *virtualisation* (incl. most specifically `Hyper-V`) for Windows 10 and it worked (I no longer the get `SSH auth method: private key` timeout; I am slowly piecing back all the pieces I disabled to see which specific feature is a no-go for a working solution).

Until I removed all the features, my CPU was not recognising `VT-x` and `Extended Page Tables` ... once I made the above changes, `Intel Processor Identification Utility` and `CPU-Z` confirmed the CPU supported these, and I found that I was once again able to SSH without any timeout issues.

[image]